# How to use the Powershell command argument in a SendTo shortcut

Tags: windows-10, powershell, send-to

I am creating a SendTo Shortcut for opening a powershell prompt in a directory.  I've tried it 2 ways and would prefer to do it the way that I can't get working.

If I create a powershell script - C:\Users\Public\SendTo\PS Here.ps1 with only one line of code in it.

```
if(Test-Path $args[0] -PathType Leaf)  {Split-Path -path $args[0]  | cd} else { cd $args[0]}
```

and create a Shortcut C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\PowerShell Here.lnk with a command line(No Startup directory)

```
%windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Users\Public\SendTo\PS Here.ps1"
```

Doing a SendTo in explorer will open the rightclicked folder or the folder containing the rightclicked file.

If I try to do this without the intermediate file using the -Command(Which is what I would prefer) I use the shortcut(With No Startup directory)

```
%windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -NoExit -Command {if(Test-Path $args[0] -PathType Leaf)  {Split-Path -path $args[0]  | cd} else { cd $args[0]} }
```

I get following error

```
At line:1 char:95
+ ... $args[0]} } C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\P ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\Powershell' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

The MS documentation seems to imply that data after the {} command is treated as arguments
(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1  "executes the specified commands (and any parameters) as though they were typed at the PowerShell command prompt")

Any ideas on how to remove the seperate PS1 file from this(IT causes problems when this needs to be shared between multiple accounts and moved between machines?

Comment: Not that this helps you but why on earth wouldn't you just use the `directory` or `folder` entries in the registry under HKCR? If you are that determined to find out why powershell is doing this, I would ask on StackOverflow.  If you are determined to come up with a solution that works, then this is the place.  Oh.. and good luck! :)

Comment: Your use case is not a SendTo `(which specifically means open a file with the target app)` one, it is an OpenHere one.

Comment: Guess I should have taken a step back - searching on OpenHere gave me some very useful info. I was focused on figuring the commandline args for Powershell. Although I still think that would be useful to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from my comment.

This is not a PowerShell code issue or PowerShell feature.

This of course a Registry modification effort. It has been done by others for a while now. Searching for such things provides solutions for what you are after.

> ['powershell open here'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell%20open%20here%27&t=h_&ia=web)

Hit(S)

> [How to Add or Remove 'Open PowerShell window here' context menu in
> Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/60175-open-powershell-window-here-context-menu-add-windows-10-a.html#:%7E:text=The%20Open%20PowerShell%20window%20here%20context%20menu%20will,background%20of%20a%20folder,%20drive,%20library,%20or%20desktop.)
>
> [PowerShell-Open-Here-Module](https://github.com/KUTlime/PowerShell-Open-Here-Module)

Comment: The first link doesn't seem to be working - atleast for me.

Comment: I found this which might be super useful if this was the approach being taken. https://github.com/KUTlime/PowerShell-Open-Here-Module

Comment: First link 'that search one', fixed. The 2nd, is that create regkey and import and the 3rd is just doing that for you in a module. The whole regkey manual one, if you choose, sure, you and automate that, but the module already does. Yet, if you want to do it for learning, now you have resources to leverage. You can see the code of the module if you so choose.

Comment: Your answer is a *non-answer*. He did not ask for it to be added via the registry. He *specifically* asked for it to be in the SendTo folder (a preference that I understand, I do not like to clutter up my right-click menu with this registry junk). The question is about the SendTo menu "This is of course a Registry modification effort" does not answer the question.

Comment: Well, each of us has our take on whatever, but the OP accepted it, so it solved their use case, Your comment here notwithstanding,, which is also unhelpful to anyone. So, provide a better one. Lastly, I have tons of stuff on my SendTo menu for years now for varying reasons, Soooo....